# I am getting javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"departament"). Expected elements are (none)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

At my Departament class the @XmlRootElement
does not have any attributes.

This is the code for unmarshalling.

```
try
{
    JAXBContext ctx=JAXBContext.newInstance(Departament.class);
    Unmarshaller umsh=ctx.createUnmarshaller();
    Departament d=(Departament) umsh.unmarshal(new File("IT.xml"));
    //System.out.println(d);

}
```

Is there anything that i've missed? :(

The generated xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<departament>

<nume>IT</nume>

<NumarMembri>4</NumarMembri>

-<Angajati>

-<Angajat>

<id>54943</id>

<nume>Pop Alexandru</nume>

<varsta>45</varsta>

<salariu>4000.0</salariu>

</Angajat>

</Angajati>

</departament>
```

Comment: Add the XML which you are trying to parse.

Comment: I don't understand you are trying to marshal POJO to xml or unmarshal xml to POJO? From your question it seems you want to marshal, but the code is using `Unmarshaller` ?

Comment: @svasa before my comment in the OP was instead of the XML a JAXB class.

Comment: With your Java code and XML file I get another error: `The standalone document declaration value must be "yes" or "no", not "true".`